# Sails: increase bodyParser limits

Tags: sails.js

In my app (sails 0.12.0) I want to extend a limit of bytes send upon POST request. So in my `config/http.js` I am uncommenting `bodyParser` and set it to:

```
module.exports.http = {

    ...

    middleware: {
        ...

        bodyParser: (function () {
            var opts = {limit: 1024*1024*5}; // set it to 5 megabytes
            var fn;

            // Default to built-in bodyParser:
            fn = require('skipper');
            return fn(opts);

        })()

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

But now each my request seems to hang and in result I get `502 bad gateway` in every request sent from browser.

So:

- how do I initialize correctly `skipper` and extend allowed bytes limit?
- why all my request now ends up with 502?

**EDIT** as @sgress454 inquired about where exactly `bodyParser` is located I'have decided to precise it in initial question. In short it was located just where it is commented out in default config - under `middleware` object.

It turns out it's a bug and the [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3592) has been created, so please follow it for further development.

Comment: Are you placing the `bodyParser` config directly under `module.exports.http`, or are you uncommenting the `middleware:` wrapper property in that file as well?  Due to an [issue in the Sails config loader](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3592), `bodyParser` config must be specified directly under `module.exports.http`.  Re: the 502 error, that I can't speak to--is it something you're getting after a timeout?  If the request is hanging, you shouldn't be getting a response at all.

Comment: wow!!.. as to I see that you have opened this issue half an hour ago it leads me to conclusion that I was the only one encountered this bug and it was reproduced and issued thanks to you. Looking forwards for developer comments.

Comment: So...that's a yes?  Putting the config under `module.exports.http` resolves the issue?  I wish I could say this has _never_ been encountered before, but it's been infrequent enough that it has not gotten the attention it deserved.  We have a better issue-handling process now, so now that the `bodyParser` problem has popped up again thanks to you, we should be able to address it fairly easily.

Comment: yes, putting `bodyParser` out from `middleware` object and putting right into `module.exports.http` worked for me. I do not know whether I've done it in elegant way or not, but I have declared a `skipper` variable before `module.exports.http` equal to `require('skipper')( { limit: 1024*1024*5 } );` and then in the `bodyParser` I just return `skipper`.

Answer (score 2):

The [bug](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3592) as has not been updated, but this now works for me in Sails 1.2.3.

Specifically, using the example `bodyParser` in the default `config/http.js`:

```
...
bodyParser: (function _configureBodyParser(){
  var skipper = require('skipper');
  var middlewareFn = skipper({
    // strict: true,
    limit: '10mb',
  });
  return middlewareFn;
})(),
...
```

Note that the original question was missing `()` in the `bodyParser` definition.