# Increase sails bodyP

Tags: file-upload, sails.js, limit, body-parser, sails-skipper

In my app (sails 0.12.0) I want to extend a limit of bytes send upon POST request. So I've followed the comments in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548287/sails-increase-bodyparser-limits)

```
var skipper = require('skipper');
skipper.limit = 1024*1024*100;

middleware: {
    bodyParser: skipper
}
```

I still get an error:

```
 "data": {
    "code": "E_EXCEEDS_UPLOAD_LIMIT",
    "name": "Upload Error",
    "maxBytes": 15000000,
    "written": 15007474,
    "message": "Upload limit of 15000000 bytes exceeded (15007474 bytes written)"
  }
```

I've also tried to add the code below directly under `module.exports.http` and then I've tried to add it in the `middleware` only.

```
  bodyParser: (function () {
    var opts = {limit:'50mb'};
    var fn;

    // Default to built-in bodyParser:
    fn = require('skipper');
    return fn(opts);

  })
```

My question is: Why none of these codes work and how can I increase the limit. The solution can be not elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Everything that you need - set

> maxBytes

attribute in object of options to upload() method of skipper Upstream.

```
req.file('image').upload({maxBytes: 50000000}, function (err, uploadedFiles) {
     if (err) return res.serverError(err.message);
     if(uploadedFiles.length > 0) {
     // do with uploaded images what you want
      .....
     }
});
```

Comment: check sails version. This advice is for 0.12v

Comment: I tried it in V1.0 in sails and it is working.